# Alpine refuses to toggle list with x-show

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, alpine.js

I am trying to toggle a list of items on the page using Alpine & x-show. I want it to start as visible on the page load and be toggleable away if the user desires.
The button is behaving as expected and JS is being set correctly however the actual list is not being toggled (only flickering if I include x-transition). I'm using bootstrap for icons & classes.

```html
<div x-data="{ selectedDays: ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat'], isThisOpen: false }">
    <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <button="#" @click="isThisOpen = !isThisOpen">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center" x-bind:style="{'cursor': 'pointer'}">
                    <i class="bi bi-calendar3 h3 me-3 mb-3"></i>
                    <p class="sidebar-header mb-3 h5">Training Days</p>
                    <div class="ms-auto">
                        <i class=" fas fa-angle-left" x-cloak x-show="isThisOpen"></i>
                        <i class=" fas fa-angle-left fa-rotate-90" x-show="!isThisOpen"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
            <div class="btn-group d-grid justify-content-s-center col-6 mx-auto"
                 role="group" x-show="!isThisOpen" x-transition
            >
                <template x-for="day in ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded"
                           :class="{ 'active': selectedDays.includes(day) }"
                    >
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               x-model="selectedDays"
                               :value="day"
                               style="display: none;"
                        >
                        <span x-text="day"></span>
                    </label>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried inspecting the page, reviewing the docs and checking for JS errors. The frustrating thing is I've implemented this code in the same page earlier for a different dropdown and it works fine. This is the example that works as expected:

```html
<li x-data="{ isOpen: false }" class="goal-hierarchy">
    <button="#" @click="isOpen = ! isOpen">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center" x-bind:style="{'cursor': 'pointer'}">
            <div>
                <i class="h3 bi bi-star-fill me-3"></i>
                <span class="h5">Goals Priority</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-auto">
                <i class=" fas fa-angle-left" x-show="!isOpen"></i>
                <i class=" fas fa-angle-left fa-rotate-90" x-cloak x-show="isOpen"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>`
    <div x-data="{ items: ['Strength', 'Size', 'Power', 'Cardio'],
                   swapItems: function(indexA, indexB) {
                         let temp = this.items[indexA];
                         this.items[indexA] = this.items[indexB];
                         this.items[indexB] = temp; } }"
         x-show="isOpen" x-cloak x-transition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me, the only things to "fix" are:

- remove `="#"` from `<button="#" @click...`
- reverse the logic of *isThisOpen*: it should be initialized to *true* and where you set `x-show="isThisOpen"` you must set `x-show="!isThisOpen"` and vice versa (now the box results open when *isThisOpen* is *false*)

#### Edit

The problem is caused by a "conflict" with the class *d-grid* of bootstrap
To avoid this you can wrap the affected <div> with an external <div> which handles the display on/off:

```html
<div x-show="!isThisOpen" x-transition>
    <div class="btn-group d-grid justify-content-s-center col-6 mx-auto" role="group" > <!--x-transition-->
        <template x-for="day in ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']">
            <label class="btn btn-primary rounded" :class="{ 'active': selectedDays.includes(day) }">
                <input type="checkbox" x-model="selectedDays" :value="day" style="display: none;">
                <span x-text="day"></span>
            </label>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also replaced *x-class* with *:class* in the *<label>* and *x-value* with *:value* in the *checkbox* : this should fix the button issue as well

**NOTE**
To let the overall work, I've used:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.12.3/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

to include Alpine.js library

Comment: Good pickup on the logic inversion & `#` tags, thanks!
I've changed the above but the toggle is still not behaving as expected. I'm just seeing a slight flicker when it's toggled = false, but then the menu is still visible. This doesn't happen if toggled = true. I tried in codepen & JSfiddle with the same result.

Comment: I tested it by putting it in an existing project and, as mentioned, it works for me.
Please share your Codepen or JSfiddle

Comment: https://codepen.io/Tom-Tester-the-lessful/pen/gOQVdbP?editors=1000
For some reason the button select is now broken too... this is not my day

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the new information

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me up the wall, how did you identify the bootstrap conflict that was causing this issue? PS I've updated the JS Fiddle to reflect your response so future users can grab it if they need.

Comment: I used the browser's page inspector:  the *display:none* was added by Alpine but in the styles tab it was marked as ignored